# Using JUnit 5 with a base class with abstract test methods with annotations

Tags: java, junit, junit5

Using JUnit 5. I want to run similar tests with slight implementation differences. I want the sub classes to run in a particular order and repeat.

I use a base class

```
public abstract class BaseTest {

    @RepeatedTest(2)
    @Order(1)
    abstract void testSomething();

    @RepeatedTest(2)
    @Order(2)
    abstract void testSomethingElse();

}
```

But when I extend this class and implement the methods. It says No Tests Found.

Any ideas on how to do this?

TIA

Comment: Yes it does. ;) Back to Junit 4.